# Publish Abstract of Research paper in Researchgate before appearing in IEEE Xplore

Tags: publications, conference, plagiarism, ieee

I have 3 research papers accepted in 2 different intl. conferences in July'21 and the co-authors presented the papers already in August,21 (conferences are IEEE Sponsored, and going to index/publish by IEEE Xplore). However, none of these papers appeared in IEEE Xplore yet. Maybe it will appear few more weeks later. Now, my question is, can I publish the papers in Researchgate(only title, author names and abstract)? I mean, if IEEE Xplore rechecks the plagiarism before publishing the paper in IEEE Xplore, then it might appear the title and abstract of my paper is already in researchgate and as a result plagiarism score crosses 30%+ which might result not publishing the paper. Is my assumption true? I am worried about the plagiarism might cause an issue. In short, can I publish the title and abstract in ResearchGate to an already presented paper but before appearing in IEEE Xplore? Thank you

Comment: IEEE allows for this.  Check their policy.  They allow authors to post accepted papers on their web-site, as long you include the standard boiler plate.    For example, many papers are posted on ArXiV before they are published by the IEEE.   Also ResearchGate will 'steal' papers from ArXiV.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.